# is there any way to select columns containing a substring from the table in SQL or pyspark?

Tags: sql, pyspark

Is there any way to select columns containing a substring from the table?
I want to select columns starting with  'device_' from a database table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to filter the columns to select:

```
import re

df.select([col for col in df.columns if re.findall('^device_', col)])
```